# Java STS mechanism exception

Tags: java, web-services, security, java-metro-framework, wsit

I am trying to implement web services that use different security mechanisms to do some performance tests and compare them. I am using Java and Netbeans 7 with Glassfish. I managed to implement all the security mechanisms but i have trouble with the STS. I am following this [guide](http://metro.java.net/1.4/guide/Example_Applications.html#ahiey) in order to create the STS but after i have done all the steps and i try to run the project i get the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:
 ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.me.my.sts.MySTS cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
```

What is that and any way to overcome it ? Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently its the bug with the STS wizzard:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=210144

Changing web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>MySTSService</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>MySTSService</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

to

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>MySTSService</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

should get rid of the problem.